# Forcing HTTPS when using opsworks nginx and ELB to terminate SSL

Tags: nginx, aws-opsworks

Using Opsworks standard setup/recipes for a Rails app served via Unicorn/nginx layer.  SSL is terminated at the Elastic Load Balancer - so traffic to the rails app from ELB is always http.  So far so good.  I would like to have any request to http://domain.com to be redirected to https://domain.com

ELB has two listeners - one with port 80, and one 443.

I know that if I were running my own nginx I could setup a redirect rule... However, i want to stay within the opsworks way of doing things if possible.

Comment: Did you ever find anything that helped you with this question? What was the Opsworks way of doing this? I followed their docs but ELB still terminates/kills/throws up an error in the browser, yet i can type in the IP address and it will go through.

Comment: I ended up keeping it stupidly simple and using CloudFlare where the redirection from http to https happens.  So the ELB stays on https, no need to have the http port open at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do this in OpsWorks is to create a custom recipe that modifies `/etc/nginx/sites-available/#{application}`. In your custom cookbook:

somecookbook/recipes/nginx.rb

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy| 

      service "nginx" do
        supports :status => true
        action :nothing
      end

      # Add HTTP => HTTPS redirect      
      template "/tmp/http_redirect.conf" do
        source "nginx/http_redirect.conf.erb"
      end

      execute "redirect HTTP to HTTPS" do
        cwd "/etc/nginx/sites-available"
        command "cat #{application} /tmp/http_redirect.conf > /tmp/#{application}.conf && cat /tmp/#{application}.conf > #{application}"
        notifies :restart, "service[nginx]", :immediately
      end                                      
  end    
end
```

Then in the config:

somecookbook/templates/default/nginx/http_redirect.conf.erb

```
server {
    listen       80;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! There's just a typo, should be ".erb" for the http_redirect.conf.erb template file extension

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to use nginx on your app server to handle the redirect http -> https.
Here are a two methods to solve this.

1. redirect all requests from 80 to `https`:

   ```
   server {
      listen 80;
      return 301 https://example.com/$request_uri;
   }
   ```
2. ELB supports a header called X-FORWARDED-PROTO. 
   All HTTPS requests going through the ELB will have the value of X-FORWARDED-PROTO = “HTTPS” :

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       location / {
           if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
               rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
           }  
       }
   }
   ```